# prevent php files from being downloaded in apache or Windows Server 2008

Tags: php, apache

1. In Linux Apache, I put my php files under /var/www/html. If I don't add an index.html in every subfolders under /var/www/html, Then my php files will be listed and can be downloaded.

The question is must I configure the apache file in order to prevent listing of my php files and hence to prevent download of my php files ?

**[Edited] I want the php file to be executed and produce desired web pages but the sourcecode files not to be downloaded by anyone. My php files are placed under /var/www/html in a Ubuntu On AWS EC2. Then I try to do something like: type awsec2ip/mywebsiteRootDirectory/ , if there ain't an index.html, then the server lists my php files and allow me to right-click the php files and then download them.**

**[not so related to question 1]Also I want to ask if I only want my android application to run some php files for dealing with the database, where should I put the php files or how should I configure the apache?**

**Thanks for your help and sorry for my inexperience**

2. Similarly in Windows Server 2008, what are the proper procedures to produce the same security effect?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you want here - you don't want files to be downloaded, yet you're putting them in the web server document root? Do you mean you want them to be executed, and the result displayed, or do you not want them to be retrieved at all? In either case, adding an index.html file is not the solution you're looking for.

Comment: PHP files can't be downloaded in their original form. They are executed by the server and only result is displayed. If you don't want to allow their public execution, configure the permissions according to the desired results. Both Apache and Windows servers allow you to set permissions on files and folders. Adding an index.html file doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @rehmat Yes, they can be downloaded in their original form (just like any other file) if the server isn't configured to execute them. I do wonder if that is the underlying issue here.

Comment: @stwalkerster: thanks for mentioning this :) I commented by keeping a server in mind where the user is keeping his php files in a production environment :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess file in your web root folder `/var/www/html`:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: This does not prevent download of files if the filename is known, it only prevents listing them. As the asker mentions security, I'd assume they'd want to prevent download too.

Comment: It sounds like you need to simply add a handler to execute the php files.